# Is the use of 'of' necessary in 'all of those who'?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, all-of

Which is correct:

> We would like to thank **all of those** that believed in this project.

or:

> We would like to thank **all those** that believed in this project.

Comment: Both mean the same thing but are parsed differently.

Comment: Also, you would normally use _who_ to refer to people, not _that_.

Comment: It might be better just to say "everyone who believed".

Comment: All those in favor, say "Aye".

Answer (score 1):

In the case of "all of those" vs. "all those", it's a matter of personal preference. Personally, I would use "all those"; I think it flows better.

This Google Ngram also shows preference for "all those":

[image]

I included both "that" and "who", but as others have said, "who" *should* be used (i.e. it's not strictly incorrect to use "that") when referring to people or groups thereof.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out in the comments, either is correct, but *who* should be preferred to *that.*  If you are actually writing something that uses this phrase I would use a shorter version something along the lines of:  "We thank all those who believed in this project".  "We would like to thank" makes me wonder why you don't just thank them and makes me think along the lines of "we would like to thank, but can't" ;-)  Of course that might be your intent <shrug>.

Comment: I completely disagree with the second half of this answer. "We would like to thank" is a standard construction which means "we thank". Although people will periodically make jokes when someone uses this construction (I.e. they say "well why don't you thank them then?"), there is nothing wrong with its usage and it is widely understood.

Comment: Don't you mean 'whom', not 'who'?

Comment: @user180089 I'm one of those (apparently) old-fashioned people who uses "whom" rather than "who" as the object off verbs and prepositions, but I don't see any "who" that should be "whom" in this answer. "Who" is the subject of "believed".

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: drop *of* before possessive pronouns *its, my, our, his, her,* and *their* and the relative pronoun *that* (*Here is a list of all his accomplishments*). Drop *of* before collective and plural nouns (*Look at all the people in the stadium*).

Use *of* before singular nouns (*Did he eat all of the cake?*), the impersonal pronoun it (*Yes, he ate all of it*), and objective case pronouns *me, you, us, them, whom* (*Do all of you understand?*).

From what I read, the *of* should be avoided whenever possible.